# Secure Connector API endpoint not in VCAP_SERVICES?

Tags: ibm-cloud

I have created an API via basic secure connector (SOAP). The API works but I am wondering why I can't retrieve the endpoint URL from `VCAP_SERVICES`. Anything I miss here?

Comment: some code showing how you attempt to retrieve the VCAP data would be helpful here

Comment: This seems to be a bug in the Cloud Integration service. A workaround is to manually set the baseUrl in your code using the value from the API Details page in the Cloud Integration UI until a fix is released.

Comment: Thanks Matt, that's what I did.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the secure connector portion of the [Cloud Integration](https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/services/CloudIntegration/index.html) service in Bluemix? You might want to try the [Secure Gateway](https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/#services/SecureGateway/index.html#gettingstartedsecuregateway) service, which is newer and is basically just the secure connector as a standalone service without the rest of Cloud Integration.

"[Reaching enterprise backend with Bluemix Secure Gateway via console](https://developer.ibm.com/bluemix/2015/04/01/reaching-enterprise-backend-bluemix-secure-gateway/)" explains how to set up a Secure Gateway instance. When you create a destination, that creates an integration.ibmcloud.com URL that your app can then use to connect to your destination via the gateway. The gateway is a proxy, preserving the interface, so the cloud host URL has the same API as the destination host.

Comment: The goal was to create a private API and the SG does not offer this feature.

Comment: @RainerHochecker: Interesting. What do you mean by "private API"? How does Cloud Integration create a private API? How is the API created by Secure Gateway less private? This might be worth adding to you original question. "I'm using a secure connector in Cloud Integration instead of Secure Gateway because ..."